# CakePHP Call to a member function create() on a non-object in same Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Okay this is really odd I have the following test_sign_up action:

```
  public function test_sign_up(){

    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $signup_result = $this->request->data;

        $userData = array('User' => array(
            'username' =>$signup_result['User']['username'],
            'password'=> $signup_result['User']['password'],
            'group_id' => 2,
            'client_id' => 9999));

        $this->User->create();
    if ($this->User->saveAll($userData)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    }

}
```

Now when I try to save a user I get:

```
 Call to a member function create() on a non-object
```

Note that this function is within my `UsersController`

**update**

If I do:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
```

It works no problem, But should that be necessary when i'm already in the controller bound to the User model?

Comment: What did you tried to fix that? SO is not a debug tool.

Comment: Show where you actually instantiate a User object.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Never said it were so far ive been ive been checking the view to check if it is setup correcly i have also made sure that the data sent on fits the user table

Comment: @Cups This is the UsersController isnt it by cake magic bound to the User model?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt twig the Cake tag, silly of me.  (if there is some magic going on, shouldn't that be UserController then?)

Comment: @Cups Look at my update :)

Comment: Do you have a `$uses` property in your controller?

Comment: @MartinBean i have App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

Comment: It will have loaded the model, but only if the model is here `app/Model/User.php` with a class of `User` that extends `AppModel`

Comment: @DavidYell i have a model called user at that possition

Comment: Then you've got problems elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @DavidYell I actually just found the problem i don't know why it caused it but if i out commented the following: 

    //public $uses = array('Client', 'Website', 'Category', 'Type', 'WebsiteIssue');
 

then the problem went away

Comment: The `$uses` property designates what models to load, which is why I asked you if you had the property in your controller. You’ll need to add `'User'` to the array if you want the User model to be instantiated with your controller.

Comment: @MartinBean Can you add it as an answer so i can accept it if others come across same problem?

Comment: Sure. Just done so now with a little bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `$uses` array in your controller, then the controller will load these as models upon instantiation. For example:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array(
        'Client',
        'Website',
        'Category',
        'Type',
        'WebsiteIssue'
    );
}
```

In the above, the Users controller will *only* load the five models specified. If you want the User model to be instantiated too (as it would by default if `$uses` was not specified) then simply add `'User'` to your `$uses` array as well.

Comment: Although this will work, it's sidestepping the question. By convention working in the `UsersController` should always load the `User` model. I understood this to be the question. It's also worth noting that `$uses` will load all these models for every action in the controller, which can be inefficient if you don't need them all in every action. The use of `loadModel()` as per the comments, gives finer grained control with less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->Form->create()` instead of `$form->create()`.

You must use `$this` before helper object.

Your index.php code should looks like:

```
echo $this->Form->create("Contact");
```